# Past tense usage in a formal email

Tags: past-tense, past-participles, past-perfect

During the period between January and today, I have added many changes to my resume that i want to make an employer noticed of. I doubt between 'have done' and 'had done'.

> " I would like to inform you that some changes have been brought to my resume from
>   the first time I had contacted you through your website(January 2014) "
>
> Or
>
> " I would like to inform you that some changes have been brought to my
>   resume from the first time I have contacted through your website(January 2014)"

Please to help me resolve the problem i have with past usage once and for all, any link or doc is highly appreciated.

Comment: This smacks of *trying* to sound formal. "Changes have been brought to my resume"? Passive voice is not only weaker, but now your resume is some regal document with servants bringing it changes?

Comment: "Please note that I have changed my resume since I first contacted you in January 2014."

Comment: "My resume has undergone some important|significant|minor changes since I contacted you in January"

Comment: @AndrewLeach thank you, sounds more simple and elegant

Comment: @DigitalChris , thank you  for the sentence you provided with (even i didn't fully understood your first comment)

Comment: Thank you everybody for the help, especially the diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I would like to inform you that my resume has been updated since I contacted you in January 2014"

Comment: How beautifully simple is English of english people. Thank you very much.

Comment: That's the most complex sentence I have ever seen. :) I'd write: "My resume has been updated."

Comment: @JoeBlow, could you please explain more. Thank you.

Comment: @JoeBlow : I can beat that....  "Updated resume attached".

Comment: Ste -- excellent!